# Как сделать один и тот-же алгоритм шифрования и дешифровки

Tags: javascript, python

так вот, у меня есть в js две функции

```
function Encrypt(value) 
{
  var result="";
  for(i=0;i<value.length;i++)
  {
    if(i<value.length-1)
    {
        result+=value.charCodeAt(i)+10;
        result+="-";
    }
    else
    {
        result+=value.charCodeAt(i)+10;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function Decrypt(value)
{
  var result="";
  var array = value.split("-");

  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  {
    result+=String.fromCharCode(array[i]-10);
  }
  return result;
}
```

оно шифрует и расшифровывает строку, так вот, как мне сделать тоже самое, только в python. Чтобы на js это зашифровать и отправить на сервер который написан на python и уже там полученную строку расшифровать, и также зашифровать ответ

Comment: в русском языке нет слов "енкрипт" и "декрипт".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Encrypt(value):
    return '-'.join([ str(ord(i)+10) for i in value ])

def Decrypt(value):
    return ''.join([chr(int(i)-10) for i in value.split('-')])

print(Encrypt('Hello')) #82-111-118-118-121
print(Decrypt(Encrypt('Hello'))) #Hello
```

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: спасибо, работает это то что мне нужно

Comment: в следующий раз я буду минусовать ответы на вопросы, которые нарушают правила сайта. ваш ответ как раз является таковым.